# SSIS : big load and outofmemory exception

Tags: sql-server, out-of-memory, ssis

I'm currently working with Integration Services (SSIS) to load a big amount of XML files into a SQL server database. Each XML file content needs to be dispatched in several tables. I have at least 10000 xml files to load using the process. Everything works fine till 6000 files are loaded. After 6000 treatment, I always got an OutOfMemoryException from my first dataflow task, the first in the process.

In this script component, I just check if a value from a XML file is already present in a specific database table. If it is present, I return the matched ID, otherwise, I add a new record. To achieve it, I use a Lookup component. I use it with No cache option, for memory matter. Then in case of matching, I process the return ID in a script component. Like I said, everything works fine until more or less 6000 files are processed. After I got :

```
Description : System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PreExecute()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
```

Do you have some suggestions or some ressources which deal with performance and memory issue in SSIS ? Do you encountered similar problem ? DO you have an idea from where this memory problem could come from?

Thanks :)

EDIT:
Here is the code to check an XML against an XSD file. Can you see any memory leak?

```
public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add("", Dts.Variables["XSDFilePath"].Value.ToString());
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Dts.Variables["XMLFilePath"].Value.ToString(), settings))
            {
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.Load(reader);

                ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(XMLValidationHandler);
                document.Validate(eventHandler);
            }

            if (ValidationResult)
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }


    private void XMLValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Severity)
        {
            case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                Console.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);
                ValidationResult = false;
                break;
            case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                Console.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would start with looking at your code. This smells like memory is not being managed well within in there but more specifically, I wouldn't be able to say without seeing code, the package, sample XML etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I removed from my package a lot of tables load, just to keep the beginning and try to identify where the problem is coming from. The only code I wrote in C# is to check an XML file against an XSD file. I'm gonna add it on my post above. This is follow by two data flow tasks which use lookup component, to verify if the data isn't already present in a table, and the other one to get the last id inserted to create a parent child relationship. Everything is in a very large foreach loop, and when I look at the memory, little by little, it's going down.

Comment: Try the using construct on settings, document and eventHandler just to eliminate those as sources

Comment: Still have the problem. It occurs only on my workstation, 3gb ram. I tried on a development server, no problem... I thought in SSIS when the system runs out of memory, there is a swap on the disk even if it costs a lot in terms of performance. How can I encounter an outofmemoryexception in that case? Do I need to configure something else in case the system runs low in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the XMLDocument Object, It will load the entire document into memory and is likely the cause of your memory problem. Try instead to use the XmlValidatingReader

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlvalidatingreader.aspx

It should provide a more efficient use of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the 'answers' in this.,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/4d90afc8-0a1c-418f-9e3a-0b766f581b2c/